# Take ownership of local object field

Tags: rust, ownership

I created a `Task` struct that holds two files and an enum. For this struct, I want to implement a method that reads and decodes the input file as a WAV (audio). For that, I'm using the `wav` crate. This method should return a `Header` holding some metadata on the file and a `Vec<f32>`, which is the audio data itself.

The problem is that I only have ways to get a reference to this audio vector (`as_thirty_two_float()`). This reference is owned by the `read` object created in the first line. I am not allowed to return the reference because `read` will be disposed soon after. I am also not allowed to return the content (`*data_vector`) because "cannot move out of `*data_vector` which is behind a shared reference: move occurs because `*data_vector` has type `Vec<f32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait".

Obviously I could just clone the vector and be done with it, but I want to believe that there is a way to just take the ownership of `*data_vector` by destroying `read` in the process. Could anyone throw some light on this for me?

```
struct Task {
    input_file: File,
    output_file: File,
    effect: Effect,
}

impl Task {
    fn decode_input(&mut self) -> (Header, Vec<f32>) {
        let read = wav::read(&mut self.input_file)
            .expect("Failed to decode the input file");
        let data_vector = read.1.as_thirty_two_float() // &Vec<f32>
            .expect("Failed to extract the audio channel data");
        return (read.0, *data_vector);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`try_into_thirty_two_float()`](https://docs.rs/wav/1.0.0/wav/bit_depth/enum.BitDepth.html#method.try_into_thirty_two_float) which moves the vector out of the `BitDepth` on success or returns the `BitDepth` unchanged on failure.

```
let (header, bitdepth) = wav::read(&mut self.input_file)
    .expect("Failed to decode the input file");
let data_vector = bitdepth.try_into_thirty_two_float()
    .expect("Failed to extract the audio channel data");
(header, data_vector)
```

Comment: Oh how I didn't see that there was a method specifically for this? What a moron I am. Thank you very much. But still, in case that anyone come to face this question in another context some day, are you aware of a way to do what I originally wanted? If so, please append the explanation to your question, yes? Thanks again.

Comment: @BernardoLansing No, you cannot move out of a reference, you can only move out of a value. At best, if you have a `&mut Vec<T>`, you can [`take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html) its content, but not with a `&Vec<T>`.